# Dart2js error line numbers not accepted by source-map

Tags: javascript, debugging, dart, source-maps, dart2js

I am trying to get useful errors out of dart2js generated javascript.

By placing this code in my index.html:

```
window.addEventListener(
    'error',
    function(e){
        ga(
            'send',
            'event',
            'JS Error',
            'msg:'+e.message,
            'line:'+e.lineno+' col:'+ e.colno+' file:'+e.filename,
            {'nonInteraction':1}
        );
    },false);
```

I get google analytics to give me line-numbers and column-numbers of errors that occur for users of my website.

Then I am using Mozilla's source-map consumer to find out where the original error occurred, like this (using github/mozilla/source-map/):

```
// some code removed for readability
require(["source-map/source-map-consumer"], function(SMC) {

var input = {
    line: parseInt(line),
    column: parseInt(col)
};

// rawSourceMap contains the dart2js generated source-map
var smc = new SMC.SourceMapConsumer(rawSourceMap);

console.log(smc.originalPositionFor(input));
```

**The problem is that all I ever get is:**

```
{
"source": null,
"line": null,
"column": null,
"name": null
}
```

**While I am expecting something like**

```
{
"source": "image.dart",
"line": 324,
"column": 2,
"name": "clickController"
}
```

What I found out so far is that the line numbers of errors are something like this **`line: 6862, column: 31`** (a high line number a and a low column number).

After some testing and using `smc.eachMapping()`, I found out that linenumbers that give a result are like **`line: 7140, column: 1692`** (high line number and high column number).

**My question:**
Does anybody have an idea why the dart2js javascript file generates errors that the dart2js source-map file cannot understand? (and how to fix this)

Kind regards and thanks for any help,
Hendrik Jan

---

Some extra info:

The pubspec.yaml looks like this:

```
name: bones
description: A sample web application
dependencies:
  browser: any
  observe: any
transformers:
  - $dart2js: {"minify":true, "checked":false}
```

I've already tried `"minify":false` and `"checked":true` to no avail.

An error looks like this:

```
Uncaught Uncaught Error: Invalid argument(s) Stack Trace: Invalid argument(s) at dart.b (.../script.dart.js?0:1245:3) at F.dart.F.T (.../script.dart.js?0:479:48) at J.aF ... and so on ...
```

Comment: Have you tried to locate the source code manually the error message points to? Maybe is some bug in source-maps consumer.

Comment: You seem to be right. Some bug in my thinking or in source-map consumer. Chromium dev tools correctly applies the generated source-map, so dart2js source-map generation is not at fault.

Comment: It seems like some line/column references in the stack-trace **do not** result in a hit for the  source-map consumer, while other line/column references in the same trace **do** work. I now just (manually) walk through all returned numbers until the consumer returns useful data.

Answer (score 1):

I'm only guessing (since I don't see the stacktrace), but the top frame is probably a helper function. For example, instead of throwing an illegal argument exception inside the body dart2js might create a helper function "iae", and call that one instead.

This leads to smaller code, but the top-frame is then a function that doesn't exist in the source file. The `iae` function would also be shared by all callers and wouldn't help in debugging. Your approach of walking down the frames should yield the correct location.